# i need to get string format data in a file as it is

Tags: c#

```
namespace FileOperation
{
     class FileOperation_details
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        FileStream fileOperation = new FileStream("imp.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        int i;
        //for ( i = 0;i<=10;i++)
        //{
        //    fileOperation.WriteByte((byte)i);
        //} 
        fileOperation.Position = 0;
        for(i =0;i<=10;i++)

        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(fileOperation.ReadByte()) + "");

        }
        fileOperation.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

but am getting output as ascii values of string  .ie my data in file is "welcome to india " but output is ascii values of each each character.so please help me

Comment: why you are using ReadByte()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
 string str = ((char)fileOperation.ReadByte()).ToString();
 Console.Write(str + "");
```